# Firebase user login managing connection with API

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm quite new to firebase and I am looking for best practices using it, maybe I will be able to get some advices here.
What I want to do:
User login using firebase.

Problem:
I save user info in firebase but use SQL server as database where I need that user information as userId

Question: How should I approach that?
Register user on firebase and when I get response with userId and token, save it to my sql database too?

what's my current approach:
At this stage we're thinking of creating new users via admin panel (and then these users can sign in)
Would it be good approach to add user to sql database, send email to finish registration (create pasword) and then add this user to firebase, and with response send request to my backend where I update user that he's verified, add userId and token?

Answer (score 1):

It's very common to store additional information about Firebase Authentication users in your own database. Whether it's good in your use-case is subjective, but it's definitely common.

---

Assuming that you have a server interacting with SQL server on the user's behalf, be sure to pass the ID token from the client to the server, decode it there, and then use the UID (and other claims) from that token in your database interactions. Don't allow the user to just pass their UID, as that'd be a security risk.

For more on this scenario, see the Firebase documentation on [verifying a user through their ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

---

Your approach with an admin panel is a common first approach, but not something I'd recommend. Since you'll need to allow the user's to sign in with email/password, there is nothing keeping them from calling the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` API themselves on your project. So I'd recommend leaving the creation completely to the clients, and save yourself from having to consider that an abuse scenario.

If you want to control what users an access the data, store a list of email addresses (since you seem to associate that with uniquely identifying a user already) in the database, and check the email address in the ID token is in the list (and is marked as verified in the token).